# How to integrate php-youtube-api library in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube-api, composer-php, codeigniter-2

for few hours I'm trying to implement this library in Codeigniter but without success.
Here is [link](https://github.com/madcoda/php-youtube-api).
I tried to add it it application/libraries but I only get blank page when auto load it, I tried to load it with `$this->load->library('file');` and did not had success too. Can anybody explain me what can I do, since
in description of this library there is ,,composer installing" but I don't have that in CI. Also, there is explanation for ,,(Plain PHP project)" integration which goes like this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Madcoda\Youtube;
```

But I don't have vendor/autoload.php.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing the composer.json file, and it seems that you don't have vendor/autoload.php because you didn't run composer.

Answer (score 1):

As the library does not have support for CodeIgniter, you can add the library to CodeIgniter as detailed in their documentation [add user libraries](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/creating_libraries.html).

Essentially, you need to copy the Youtube.php file under folder lib/Dadcoda to the folder application/libraries of your CodeIgniter project.

Then, to use it within your controller

```
$params = array('key' => 'A_GOOGLE_API_KEY');
$this->load->library('Youtube', $params);
```

and then, for example use it like this:

```
$vId = "...";
$this->youtube->getVideoInfo($vId);
```

You may want to remove the namespace declaration inside Youtube.php as CodeIgniter does not use namespaces at all, and replace it with the common first line

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```